# How to change the binding of Windows key which runs Unity's Dash?

Tags: keyboard, unity-2d, qt

Currently, I am using the Unity Qt panel in my Gnome desktop, and when I press the Windows key, the Unity's dash launches, and I can't use any compiz based shortcuts.

Same behaviour is exhibited when I log in to Unity 2D as well, as the Windows key launches the dash.

I have no desire to change my Compiz shortcuts, so is there any way to change the keyboard mapping of Unity 2D's dash to something other or disable this shortcut completely?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can disable the super key using the command:

```
gconftool --set /desktop/unity/launcher/super_key_enable --type=bool 0
```

(Since GNOME 3 settings are in dconf instead of gconf, and unity became a plugin. The method thus became: `dconf write /org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/show-launcher '""'`)

Then you can define a keyboard shortcut with your preferred method to launch the following command:

```
dbus-send --type=method_call --dest=com.canonical.Unity2d /Dash com.canonical.Unity2d.Dash.activateHome
```

This will trigger Unity Home Dash

Comment: I mapped it to <caps_locks>

Comment: That launch command didn't work for me, I had to use `--dest=com.canonical.Unity2d.Dash` when using the daily build for Unity 2D.

Comment: I guess this method doesn't work anymore in 12.04?

Comment: Unity 2d is not available anymore. How to open a specific lens using dbus in unity 3d?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 does not work.

Answer (score 9):

I just installed Ubuntu 11.04 and I was able to use gconf-editor to change the shortcut key.

**Make sure you're not running gnome-do!** (If it's set to use your key combo, the Dash won't be able to bind to those keys.)

Open a terminal and run `gconf-editor`

Navigate to this key:

```
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/show_launcher
```

Modify the show_launcher key to a single key value.

[image: The key in gconf-editor]

I set the value to `<Super>space` and now <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> opens the dash instead of Super. Note that if you use a key combo, it seems to take a minute before you can use that to invoke the Dash. You also need to complete the key combo quickly.

---

If you want a more user-friendly interface, you can use the command line:

```
gconftool --set /apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell/screen0/options/show_launcher --type=string "<Super>space"
```

Or use [compizconfig-settings-manager](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compizconfig-settings-manager)

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

In the Desktop section, select Ubuntu Unity Plugin. Set Key to show the launcher to be your desired keys. Again, it takes a minute before you can invoke the Dash.

Comment: Oh man you just saved me from suicide :)  Thanks.

Comment: Great! Just tried the `gconftool` command in Ubuntu 12.04.1. Works like a charm!

Comment: I just realized that `Super`+`Tab` already activates the launcher in a nice way. Thus, I simply reset the `show_launcher` value to `""`.

Answer (score 6):

It is not planned for now to make it configurable though it is planned to deactivate that shortcut by default, see [bug #705076](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity-2d/+bug/705076)

Answer (score 2):

Run (Alt+F2 or Synapse) gconf-editor.  Navigate to Desktop>Unity>Launcher.  Uncheck the box for super_key_enable.

Comment: You should improve your answer by adding more details or screenshots to help take this from "an answer" to an "awesome answer"

Answer (score 0):

For Unity-2D in Ubuntu 12.04, the following command worked for me:

```
dconf write /com/canonical/unity-2d/launcher/super-key-enable false
```

see http://wtanaka.com/node/8025