# Fn+F2 LCD/CRT display toggle stopped working in 11.04

Tags: 11.04, multiple-monitors, display

After an upgrade from 10.10 to 11.04 Fn+F2 LCD/CRT display toggle button stopped working on my MSI U230 Light. Instead, pressing Fn+F2 opens Dash.

Is there any other way to toggle between LCD/CRT or reenable Fn+F2 key?

Comment: Checkt reply #4 here http://askubuntu.com/questions/21934/how-to-change-the-binding-of-windows-key-which-runs-unitys-dash Maybe you have fn+f2 there instead of super.

Comment: I have similar problem with Fn+F4 (supposed to toggle displays) on HP ProBook.Apparently it gives the 'Win' button. But it works OK under Gnome and the problem is related to Unity only.

Comment: I have a similar problem - [posted just today about it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/57770/). Its not hardware, nor bios. 11.04+Unity broke it. This had worked under 10.10 and earlier, for 2+ years, and now its broken. Please let me know if you managed to solve this.. thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that your computer's BIOS is converting the <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> key press into <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or similar.  Many of the Unity shortcuts make use of this key, which might explain what you are seeing.

That is the key sequence used to bring up the screen configuration dialog on modern versions of Windows, and Microsoft has suggested that manufacturers make the BIOS map their old <kbd>Fn</kbd> based shortcuts to the new key sequence.  A more technical description of this can be found [here](http://mjg59.livejournal.com/121851.html).

If this is what you are seeing, then there isn't much that can be done: the key sequence remapping is being done at such a low level that Linux can't distinguish the key press from you actually typing <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.  It will probably require Unity to catch this key sequence and do the display toggle itself.

I've filed a bug report about this here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/778277

Comment: You are right about Win+P key press. Pressing Fn+F2 twice inserts character "p" to Dashboard's search box. 

Anyway, I found a workaround - it still possible to switch displays from the login screen.