# How do I change the trash keyboard shortcut?

Tags: 11.04, unity, shortcut-keys

After upgrading to Natty I found that the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> shortcut is mapped to the trash.  I changed it to run a terminal in the keyboard shortcuts, but it did not change the mapping and I do not see where this shortcut is coming from.  How do I remove this shortcut?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a lame default IMO.

For those of us who can't give up their <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Foo</kbd> keyboard shortcuts, here's how you can disable the unity dash key binding to the <kbd>Super</kbd>/<kbd>Win</kbd> key, and continue to use your <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Foo</kbd> keyboard shortcuts.

[How to change the binding of Windows key which runs Unity's Dash?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21934/how-to-change-the-binding-of-windows-key-which-runs-unitys-dash)

TIP: Bind <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to the Unity Dash (replaces gnome-do)

Comment: After 5 years, this blsht is still exist. Thanks from 2016 for Super+Space hint.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately it looks like this currently is hard-coded in Unity (in src/TrashLauncherIcon.cpp).

Answer (score 0):

The terminal now starts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> by default. I guess, you can't use the win-key for shortcuts any longer, since it's the Unity-Dash-key.

Comment: Does this mean that all windows key shortcuts will not work?

Comment: I believe so. I just tried it and it didn't work for me either, even if it's not a shown letter from the unity-bar.

Comment: I have Super+T enabled for gnome-terminal in my laptop but I can't remember how I did that. I can't do it in my desktop. Both 16-04. In the Laptop the long press on <Super> won't display the shortcut reminder anymore (what I don't miss).

Answer (score 0):

"I guess, you can't use the win-key for shortcuts any longer, since it's the Unity-Dash-key."

False: I have <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> (lock), <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (Desktop) working. Still searching how to get <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch a terminal and <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to launch a sudo terminal