# Shortcut key for rubbish bin

Tags: launcher, trash, shortcuts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do do I change the trash keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40427/do-do-i-change-the-trash-keyboard-shortcut)

In the launcher, the Rubbish Bin is given the shortcut `Super+t`.  I assume this is because it was named 'Trash Can' or something in the original language.  I just wondered if there is any way of changing the letter of this shortcut because it's something that's mildly annoying to me.  I'd rather have `Super+t` open a terminal like I had in 10.10.

Comment: I believe we usually call this 'bin' or 'trash'. 'Rubbish bin' or 'trash can' contain rotten food, not rotten files.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently unable to help with rename the shortcut <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> to trash in the launcher, but I am working on it.  However, I can point you in the direction of where to change the shortcut for the terminal.

To change the default shortcut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you will need to ensure you have the 'Compizconfig Settings Manager' (CCSM) installed.  To install, issue the following command from a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Once installed, or if it is already installed, start CCSM.  In CCSM, select 'Gnome Compatibility', and select the 'Commands' tab.  Here you can change the terminal launcher shortcut.

[image]

**UPDATE**
There is indication that the shortcut for trash is currently hard-coded in Unity.  See => [How do I change the trash keyboard shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40427/do-do-i-change-the-trash-keyboard-shortcut)

Comment: I actually already have `Hyper+t` set to open a terminal.  It's close enough.