# Is is possible to change Super + T to terminal?

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.04

So now that 14.04 was released and the most active questions on this are from 2011 to 2012 ([[1]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35688/how-can-i-change-unitys-super-t-binding-to-something-else) and [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40427/how-do-i-change-the-trash-keyboard-shortcut)), I'd like to ask again just out of hope:

Is it possible to change <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> from starting the trash to starting the terminal without altering all the other shortcuts related to <kbd>Super</kbd>?

Or what are your current best practices to deal with this?

Comment: related question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/35688/how-can-i-change-unitys-super-t-binding-to-something-else

Comment: and probably a duplicate anyway: http://askubuntu.com/questions/40427/how-do-i-change-the-trash-keyboard-shortcut

Comment: Yes those were the 2 questions I addressed. They are very old.

Comment: How do I deal with this? I just lock the terminal to the ninth position on the launcher and use Super+9.

Answer (score 0):

Install CompizConfig:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then run it from the dash and look for the section called key bindings or something similar. Look for the one that opens the terminal, and you can change the keybindings there.