# Change the keyboard shortcut for launching the dash in 13.04?

Tags: unity, 13.04, shortcut-keys, launcher

When I hit the `Meta` key I get the Unity launcher. I don't like this and would like to change it.

I tried the answers from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21934/how-to-change-the-binding-of-windows-key-which-runs-unitys-dash) with no luck. Mostly because the following settings directories referenced there don't exist on 13.04:

```
/desktop/unity
/apps/compiz-1/plugins/unityshell
/com/canonical/unity-2d/
```

Seems somebody is making it a hobby to move this setting around to a new place with each release! Can anybody figure out where the setting exists on 13.04?

Comment: Looks like it can be done with the Unity Tweak Tool

Comment: Could you perhaps add that as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the [Unity Tweak Tool](https://launchpad.net/unity-tweak-tool)

```
sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool
```

Look for the keyboard shortcuts preference pane.